# Setting Up Neo4j Database Authentication on Windows Azure

Tags: authentication, azure, neo4j

I set up a Neo4j database on Azure following this [guide](http://de.slideshare.net/neo4j/neo4j-on-azure-step-by-step-22598695).  The set-up process went fine.  The issue I'm having is that the database is not asking for a username or password when I access it though the public port.  In other words, anyone can access and edit the database by simply navigating to the URL.  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to set up authentication?

Answer (score 1):

First: That's a fairly old walkthrough, with the v1.8 version of Neo4j running on the *preview* of Virtual Machines. And that image had a pre-set username and password. Look closely at the login box:

```
"The server says neo4j graphdb"
```

Those two will be your username and password.

Note: This is not the case if you use the latest 2.0x image in VM Depot.

Comment: I'm using the latest version, 2.0.1.  A couple things have changed on Azure, but it's almost entirely the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by modifying the /conf/neo4j-server.properties file and following the instructions at the github repo.

```
# Basic Auth-Filter-Extension
# See docs here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension
org.neo4j.server.credentials=your_user_name:your_password
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.server.extension.auth=/auth
```